# $\lim_{n\to\infty} d^{-n}e^{o(n)}, d>1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I think it's rather a silly question, but I have some problems to say definitely what
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}d^{-n}e^{o(n)} 
$$
is, where $d>1$.

Of course, $d^{-n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Is it true that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{o(n)}<\infty,
$$
(i.e. the limit exists and is, say, $c<\infty$), since for large n 
$$
e^{o(n)}<e^n?
$$
If yes, then I can compute the limit as the product of the limits, getting
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}d^{-n}e^{o(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}d^{-n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{o(n)}=0\cdot c=0.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not necessarily true since the exponent may also diverge to infinity. Take for example $\log n$ or $\sqrt n$.

Try the following:

\begin{align}
d^{-n}e^{o(n)} &= e^{-n\log d}e^{o(n)}\\
&= e^{-n\log d+o(n)} \\
&= e^{-n(\log d-o(n)/n)} \\
\end{align}

And recall that $o(n)/n\to0$. Try and continue from here.

Comment: That is, for large $n$, we have that $d^{-n}e^{o(n)}=e^{-n\log d}$ and this tends to 0 as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Rhjg, not exactly. What can you say about $\log d$, and therefore what can you say about $\log d-o(n)/n$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: Do you mean that $\log d\in o(n)$ and therefore $\log(d)-o(n)/n\in o(n)$?

Comment: @Rhjg, no, $d$ is constant. Therefore $\log d$ is constant. What I mean is $d>1$ therefore $\log d>0$, so for sufficiently large $n$ we have $|o(n)/n|<(\log d) / 2$, therefore $\log d - o(n)/n > (\log d) / 2$ therefore $d^{-n}e^{o(n)} < e^{-n(\log d) / 2} = d^{-n/2}\to 0$

Comment: Ok, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}d^{-n}e^{o(n)}<0$. ?

Comment: No, the limit equals 0, since it's a positive function bounded by a function that approaches zero.

Comment: Ah, you mean $0\leqslant d^{-n}e^{o(n)}<d^{-n/2}$. The right side tends to 0, hence we have $0\leqslant d^{-n}e^{o(n)}<0$ for $n\to\infty$, meaning that it is 0.